# Manipulating python json dictionaries

Tags: python

I am trying to manipulate some JSON in python but I am getting really stuck. I can work with basic dictionaries in python but not this. I am trying to pull out individual variable values (AKA the value part of a key-value pair).

```
data = json.dumps({ 
"example":[
 {
     "id": "001",
     "somefield": "yes",
     "text": "This is text",
     "options":[
        {
           "firstop": "yesitis",
           "secondop":1
        }
     ],
     "length":5
  },
  ]
```

There are many other entries within "example", but this is the first. I have tried doing the equivalent of (And this works by printing out everything):

```
print json.loads(data)['example']
```

But doing the following does not work:

```
    print json.loads(data)['example']['id']
```

I don't know how to access variables one by one. I've been experimenting with variations of "for key, value in json.loads(data)['example']:" etc. but they all tell me that there are too many values to unpack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you look at the format you'll see it's actually a list containing dictionaries.

try:

```
print json.loads(data)['example'][0]['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try as well [jsontree](http://pythonhosted.org/jsontree/)

```
>>> mytree = jsontree()
>>> mytree.something.there = 4
>>> mytree['something']['there'] == 5
>>> False
>>> mytree['something']['there'] == 4
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "example" is a list of json :
If you want to access id or other keys

```
print json.loads(data)['example'][0]['id']
print json.loads(data)['example'][0]['text']  ...
```

If you want to access keys inside options :

```
print json.loads(data)['example'][0]['options'][0]['firstop']
```