# How do I make sure successed2000.json has more than 1000 files, not 25 files?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have sucessed json file format of image 1. I have 2,000 csv data, and I want 2,000 json files that are kept in 25 rather than nextpage and skip.

[image]

[image]

Comment: make question more descriptive

Comment: If you look at the top image, how do you get pagesize: 25 to 2000?

Answer (score 0):

Um, do you mean "How do i change the `pageSize` value from 25 to 2000?

json works as dictionaries in python. So i think you should be able to do:

```
dataJson['nextPage']['pageSize'] = 2000
```

ref: [Manipulating python json dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381435/manipulating-python-json-dictionaries)

Or did i misunderstand your question?

Comment: I do not think it has changed. Can you see the image at the end? Is this it?

Comment: I think i know what your question is. "How do i make my response pagesize 2000 instead of 25?". This looks like an azure related question rather than python/json. I think you have to add some parameters to your requests or something like that.

Sorry, don't know much about azure.

Comment: I want to keep what's in the right json file. Now I'm limited to 25, but I want about 2000. And not skip.